# Jetpack Compose: scroll to bottom of screen on keyboard open

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack-compose

I want to scroll the layout (which is NOT a LazyColumn) to the very bottom once the keyboard is open. The keyboard opening detection works fine:

```
var parentSize by remember {
    mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)
}
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

DisposableEffect(view) {
    scope.launch {
        scrollState.animateScrollTo(parentSize.height.toInt())
    }
    val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val isKeyboardOpen = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)
            ?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: true
        if (isKeyboardOpen) {
            scope.launch {
                scrollState.animateScrollTo(parentSize.height.toInt())
            }
        }
    }

    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
    onDispose {
        view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
    }
}

OutlinedTextField(
    value = uiState.emailInput,
    onValueChange = { onEmailInputChanged(it) },
    label = { Text(text = stringResource(id = C.string.email)) },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Next
    ),
    singleLine = true,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(horizontal = Dimen.medium)
        .onFocusChanged {
            scope.launch {
                scrollState.animateScrollTo(parentSize.height.toInt())
            }
        }
)
// the very bottom view
Button(
                onClick = { onLoginClicked() },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.Bottom)
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = Dimen.veryLarge)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                        //here u can access the parent layout coordinate size
                        parentSize = it.parentLayoutCoordinates?.parentLayoutCoordinates?.size?.toSize()?: Size.Zero
                    }
                    .padding(start = Dimen.medium, end = Dimen.medium, bottom = Dimen.medium),
                enabled = !uiState.isLoading && uiState.inputCorrect,
            )
```

However, no matter what I do, the automatic scrolling doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is parentSize?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I added the very bottom view that calculates the parent size

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollState.maxValue`. As well as, if you can, replace `animateScrollTo` with `scrollTo`.

Finally your code can be seen as follows:

```
scope.launch {
    scrollState.scrollTo(scrollState.maxValue)
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, `maxValue` doesn't quite scroll to the absolute end of the content.